# Why connection in Python's DB-API does not have "begin" operation?

Tags: python, sql, python-db-api

Working with cursors in mysql-python I used to call "BEGIN;", "COMMIT;", and "ROLLBACK;" explicitly as follows:

```
try:
    cursor.execute("BEGIN;")
    # some statements
    cursor.execute("COMMIT;")
except:
    cursor.execute("ROLLBACK;")
```

then, I found out that the underlying connection object has the corresponding methods:

```
try:
    cursor.connection.begin()
    # some statements
    cursor.connection.commit()
except:
    cursor.connection.rollback()
```

Inspecting the [DB-API PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) I found out that it does not mention the begin() method for the connection object, even for the extensions.

Mysql-python, by the way, throws the DeprecationWarning, when you use the method. sqlite3.connection, for example, does not have the method at all.

And the question is why there is no such method in the PEP? Is the statement somehow optional, is it enough to invoke commit() instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decided to answer myself:

A [thread about DB API 2.0 transactions](http://groups.google.ru/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/80d0bf3bacd47400) in python-list and the following excerpt from the noticeable book [SQL The Complete Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071592555) make me think that DB API implements SQL1 standard behaviour:

> The first version of the SQL standard
>   (SQL1) defined an implicit transaction
>   mode, based  on the transaction
>   support in the early releases of DB2.
>   In implicit mode, only the COMMIT  and
>   ROLLBACK statements are supported. A
>   SQL transaction automatically begins
>   with the  first SQL statement executed
>   by a user or a program and ends when a
>   COMMIT or ROLLBACK  is executed. The
>   end of one transaction implicitly
>   starts a new one.

Explicit transaction mode (the SQL2 and SQL:1999) seems to be handy when the RDBSM supports autocommit mode and the current connection is in that mode, but DB API just does not reflect it.

Answer (score 8):

look [a this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219326/how-do-i-do-database-transactions-with-psycopg2-python-db-api). Generally the "protocol" to use with transactions is:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute(...)
except DatabaseError:
    conn.rollback()
    raise
else:
    conn.commit()
finally:
    cursor.close()
```

Starting from python 2.6 [sqlite `Connection` objects can be used as context managers that automatically commit or rollback transactions](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#using-the-connection-as-a-context-manager).

Comment: Thank you for the useful link to the neighbour question. This is not the answer for my question but it sheds some light on the possible reasons.

Comment: @newtower: You are right, i was in doubt to answer or just post a comment but doing so i could post that little snip.

Comment: By the way, though wrapping the connection with a context manager is usefull, I prefer to reuse the connection in adjacent queries, but cursor classes do not implement the contextmanager interface, even in python 2.6.

Comment: According to the documentation, it seems it should be `conn.rollback()`, `conn.commit()` rather than `cursor.rollback()`, `cursor.commit()`. Am I missing something?