# Does a transaction start even on SELECT?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I read in the [docs](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) :

> ...since transactions start when a cursor execute a query, but end when COMMIT or ROLLBACK is executed by the 
>   Connection object.

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(user="root", db="test")
c = db.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM books")
print c.fetchall()
```

I suspect that MySQLdb starts a transaction even on queries that do not modify data (like SELECT), because it is difficult to know if a query only reads data and doesn't write it.

1. Is it true?
2. If so, this means i should do `cursor.commit()` after every query, to be sure that no table is locked?
3. Other issues i am not aware of?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `SELECT` statement is like other so the transaction starts.

If you want to avoid this, you could do something like that:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
SELECT * FROM books ;
COMMIT ;
```

In detail:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED ;
```

says that the following instruction could read the rows that have been modified but that haven't received a `COMMIT` yet.
That kind of transaction dind't get exclusive locks.

The second part `SELECT * FROM books ;` is obviously a `SQL statement` and the third part `COMMIT ;` ends the transaction and make it "permanent".
In that case no writes are done, so the `COMMIT` is used only to end the transaction and

Comment: Could you please explain your example, and why `commit` is still needed?

Comment: @warwaruk : is this question been updated? Because I remember that it was different.

Comment: Ok, so I don't remember well. However, he aske at point 2 if he have to do `cursor.commit` after every update and i told him that, if he use that snippet of sql query, he could even forget about "committing the cursor every query". For more details, please see the update that i'm going to do.

Answer (score 2):

1. it is true, <strike>but it as well automatically commits after each query, because mysql clients start with `autocommit=1` by default</strike>
2. you should not, since `SELECT` does not hold any locks after the statement is executed. In practice, explicit commits might even cause a significant slow down.
3. Just might be useful: [Why connection in Python's DB-API does not have "begin" operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546926/why-connection-in-pythons-db-api-does-not-have-begin-operation)

Comment: `autocommit=1` is not true for Pythons `MySQLdb`! You have to set this explicitly. That's a common source for misunderstandings in Python a la "Where is the data I just inserted?".

Comment: @ocaso-protal, hmm, true. Why do I still think so, having removed the `init_command` paramerer setting autocommit=0 from my connection settings a long time ago?