# Postgresql table update

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg

I updated a database table using postgresql from python
My code was

```
import psycopg2
connection=psycopg2.connect("dbname=homedb user=ria")
cursor=connection.cursor()
l_dict= {'licence_id':1}
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM im_entry.usr_table")
rows=cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows:
   i=i+1
   p = findmax(row)
   #print p
   idn="id"
   idn=idn+str(i)


   cursor.execute("UPDATE im_entry.pr_table SET (selected_entry) = ('"+p+"') WHERE  image_1d ='"+idn+"'")
   print 'DATABASE TO PRINT'
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM im_entry.pr_table")
rows=cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row
```

I got the updated table displayed

But when i display updated table by psql as
homedb=# SELECT * FROM im_entry.pr_table; 
i got an empty table displayed..what is wrong?? please help me

Comment: I solved it myself..I have forgotten to  use COMMIT with in the procedure after INSERT and UPDATE statement in order to COMMIT the changes that were made!!

Comment: What does the `findmax()` function do exactly? I don't think the loop is necessary at all but that depends on what `findmax()` is doing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably not committing the transaction, i.e. you need a `connection.commit()` after all your updates.

There are various different settings you can make to the isolation level, e.g. autocommit, so you don't need to issue commits yourself.  See, for example, [How do I do database transactions with psycopg2/python db api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219326/how-do-i-do-database-transactions-with-psycopg2-python-db-api)